# Program closing thread when button pressed Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#

I realize there are similar questions here and I have looked at them, I just can't apply the solutions to my own problem.

I am writing an MP3 player for a Pi using visual studio (C#) on a PC, then using Mono on the Pi to run it. As Mono does not seem to have an MP3 library (happy to be corrected) my workaround is to use a gui interface to control a command line mp3 player (omxplayer). I have a working test interface which i ssh across to the Pi from my PC to test each time.

The problem is when I hit Button1 to run it, it works fine in that the mp3 plays. But as soon as I hit button 2 to send the app the "p" key which should pause the program, it just quit out. Ultimately I will have a bunch of buttons sending key presses to control it like next skip stop etc. I have tested the functionality from a terminal and it works fine. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is my code.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo;
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Button Clicked";
            procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("omxplayer", "/home/pi/Music/Debug/Mutter.mp3 &");
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{p}");
        }
    }
}
```

As I tried to explain in the comments, not global, but not strictly correct.
C# did this

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Button Clicked";
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("omxplayer", "/home/pi/Music/Debug/Mutter.mp3 &");
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();
    }
```

Comment: a lot of questions/issues come from a misunderstanding or wrong assumptions. my comment is just for clarification. so it is very important that you try to be as precise as possible. - but i will respect this and leave you alone. good luck

Comment: I am new to this forum, but at almost 60 not new to the world, I just get tired of negative input from people trying to big note themselves over others. My problem is not helped by your post. The explanation of my issue is very clear, and not effected by my small error in terminology. I work on the principle never speak unless it improves on silence.

Comment: the comment section is for clarification and only for clarification. we/i cannot look into your brain, we can only read what you have written and that is the only information we can work with. you should only expect an answer to your question in the answer section, so only in the answer section you can expect something that will help you with your issue.

Comment: @Greywolf - Please don't **sigh** here. We have a policy of "No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language."

Comment: Small clarification: "as soon as I hit button 2 to send the app the "p" key which should pause the program" - you probably mean button 3? Regarding the question: If I did not miss anything, clicking the button should put the form into focus. Thus the "p" will get sent to the form, not to your mp3 player.

Comment: But, if I interpret "it just quit out" correctly, the form closes then? Or does the player close?

Comment: Clarification then, Yep Button 3 is meant to pause playing, Button 2 quits. Numbering is out of Kilter due to the order I made them in. I Did have some issue when initially I used proc.WaitForExit(); in that nothing happened at all, program locked completely until the track ended. I messed about trying to make it a background process but in the end SendKeys.Send("{p}"); still made the app exit. So in order to simplify, I just removed the proc.WaitForExit(); for simplicity. Like I said, it all works fine from the Pi terminal, including the pause.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming omxplayer is just waiting for input from standard input<sup>1</sup>, you should just be able to redirect that (as you're currently doing for standard output) and send characters to it that way. No need for `SendKeys`.

E.g. it would be

```
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
```

And then to pause should be:

```
proc.StandardInput.Write('p');
```

You may have to also either add a `Flush` call after that or turn on `AutoFlush` on the stream.

---

<sup>1</sup>I can't try this out myself presently, so have to build on an assumption

Comment: Hey Thanks, got excited for a tick then, sadly no cigar. I moved the proc declaration back up the top as it did not see it when defined in the button1. But it still exits on button 3. Just to make sure it is the code for button press I commented it out and it did not exit. So it is definitely caused by the button press.

Comment: Correction, fault code PEBCAK, as my ex wife would say I had a boy look. I did not add the line procStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true; I looked quickly and thought it was there. But it was Standard Output. Thank you very much for your help. many hours lost on this one for me. Such a simple solution in the end. Cheers

Comment: @Greywolf as you are new to SO please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I don't have all the answers for you. but writing a .net solution for the PI seems more problem than necessary.

I would stick with simple C or C++ and stick with things that are highly compatible with Linux

see this 20 years plus library for reading MP3 files

libmpg123 - https://www.mpg123.de/api/